# DocuSign Send on Behalf Of (SOBO): User Names with Commas

Tags: coldfusion, docusignapi

I have a ColdFusion code implementing DocuSign REST API calls. They are working fine except when the user's name in DocuSign is like: `LastName, FirstName` format. So basically, `Doe, John` is failing in the sense that the `Reply To Email` in both Desktop OutLook and online OutLook--and possibly other clients-- becomes like: `Doe@mydomain.com; john@mydomain.com` in the Reply to address bar in the email clients.

But... if the user's name was like `John Doe` then no problem.

Anyway, my relevant code is inside a `CFHTTP` call as:

```
<SendOnBehalfOf>#SOBOEMAIL#;#SOBONAME#</SendOnBehalfOf></DocuSignCredentials>">
```

but it shouldn't matter what programming envrironment--the comma in the user name is the problem, always. I have tried to just be #SOBONAME# or just #SOBOEMAIL# but no luck.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought- have you tried escaping the comma (,) character in XML?  Something like:

```
<SendOnBehalfOf>#SOBOEMAIL#;Doe&#44;John</SendOnBehalfOf></DocuSignCredentials>">
```

Comment: Thanks. That didn't work. Firstly, the # character is special in ColdFusion. Also, SOBONAME is a dynamic value. Maybe there is some other syntax to escape the comma?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why exactly, but I managed to massage the name in the Reply to using ColdFusion's string manipulation and then used the following in the Envelope's JSON code.

```
  ""emailSettings"": {
      ""replyEmailAddressOverride"": ""#SOBOEMAIL#"",
      ""replyEmailNameOverride"": ""#fullnameProper#"",

    },
```

No problem now. The `fullnameproper` is the one result of the CF string work.

HTH.